# Got InterruptedException while executing word count mapreduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-sandbox

I have installed Cloudera VM version 5.8 on my machine. When I execute word count mapreduce job, it throws below exception.

```
`16/09/06 06:55:49 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1281)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:862)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.endBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:600)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:789)
`
```

But the job completes successfully. Could someone please help me resolve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

You can ignore this warning. It's a bug in Hadoop.

There is an issue for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-10429

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with Cloudera VM.
 
So I installed [Hortonworks VM](http://hortonworks.com/downloads/#sandbox) and I did not face any such issue with it.

Comment: It would be interesting to know which version of Hortonworks that you used.